# How add various hidden divs (content) for each button with Slide toggle function

Tags: javascript, html

I've looked everywhere but couldn't find nothing similar.

```
> I need this Slide toggle function  to work for various hidden divs
> (that contain images and text) that belong to each button,if it's
> possible the hidden divs slide from the right or even from bottom to
> up.Also if it's possible to add hoover on buttons to let the user know that
they are buttons to click on them,
```

if there is more explanation needed please let me know.I would appreciate the help!

[Slide toggle from right- Js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hcmLw/2/)

the idea explanation is here:

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "php error 150"?

Comment: Do you mean the error is "If MySQL reports an error number 1005 from a CREATE TABLE statement, and the error message refers to error 150, table creation failed because a foreign key constraint was not correctly formed." ?

Comment: You got the html for that image above

Comment: I'm afraid I don't, don't even know how to start it, it's an idea that came about a week ago and have been looking since for something similar the jsfiddle posted on the question was the only similar thing I could find for the function :( Ps: Nice to see you again, deeply appreciate your time and help in this and sorry for being a huge pain :(

Comment: this is similar to work off. http://jsfiddle.net/GXf45/2/

Comment: it's amazing! But is it possible to place the buttons on the left side next to the slide content? I dont even know how to put images on the buttons :(, I really wish I learned javascript years ago this is one of the biggest mistakes ever made :( for me this is a constant struggle, just dont get it

Comment: but I don't want to bother you more with this, appreciate all you helped me in which was a lot, I really hope you will gain the two bounties soon, working on it! :)

Comment: Here and I'm done, http://jsfiddle.net/GXf45/4/ try editing it yourself it's not too hard. I left in the extra stuff you can remove it if you wish.. if you remove the extra buttons on the bottom that means alot less jquery code too.

Comment: it looks good and it's sweet of you to have added the buttons,thank you for this a lot, appreciate your time & effort in this truly, I wish I could find a way to repay all the help you gave me but the only thing in mind are the bounties. Thank you again! You are a Saint! :)

Comment: No problem let me know your new account.

Comment: This is my new account: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3358505/3-boxes    I'm first preparing the new questions to post and this time I need to make sure they are accurate with details so I won't get banned again puff!

Comment: removed the buttons of the bottom by html but in javascript dont know where to go ...tried removing something and it stopped working

Comment: Cool, I'll try to remember 3-boxes, Here I cleaned it up as much as possible changed the button code added a class and id. (except the CSS) http://jsfiddle.net/GXf45/8/ also changed table width to 1000 to make the Buttons bigger so the image fits in one area.

Comment: thank you so much :) I thought you got tired of my questions xd, I do agree with you, I'm a pain when it comes to questions & 0 orientated when it comes to html/javascript, but always appreciate all your time and effort in helping me :) You are a very kind person, it's rare to find these days...This coming week finally will start getting on adding new questions on the new account and the points, thanks for your patience

Comment: One last thing, sorry again, just need your opinion on this, as the website itself took me almost 3 months to complete is there a way to hide javascript and css layout from being copied? Hope you understand it took me ages to make it as unique as possible regarding on my work and I know that the moment it goes on the server anyone can get the stylesheet and the functions by copying the codes :( PS:New questions for next week are for another website I will be building after this one, but this first one is more personal that makes it more important for me.

Comment: sorry took ages to reply but still havent used the new account yet, going to hopefully this weekend, I'm so sorry it's just I've been stuck with personal problems that barely used the computer let alone finished the website puff, I still remember and I will keep my promise, sorry though it's taking long. take care

Answer (score 1):

If you want all fields to be mandatory, it should throw an error if either of `$name` or `$email` is empty; so you use OR. Also, if anti-spam is not 4, just throw an error, you don't have to check for `$_POST['submit']` as you have already checked it.

```
  if ($_POST['submit']) {
        if ($name != '' OR $email != '') {
                if ($human == '4') {                 
                        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
                                echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
                        } else { 
                                echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
                        }
                } else {
                        echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
                }
        } else {
            echo '<p>You need to fill in all required fields!!</p>';
        }
}
```

Comment: So what is different here?  Can you provide some discussion on the issue?

Comment: Updated the answer. Maybe this is not cause for an php error 150, whatever that is. Never came across it.