# Javascript Errors from various functions

Tags: javascript

Can someone please help me sort out a few errors from some javascript functions:
I'll point which function, error with the link of the script written in fiddle.These 
functions are working perfectly but those errors came up in web developers tool.

(1) calling Flexslider js, this is the function:

> ERROR : Uncaught ReferenceError: SyntaxHighlighter is not defined

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      SyntaxHighlighter.all();      <----- ERROR
    });
    $(window).load(function(){
      $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        start: function(slider){
          $('body').removeClass('loading');
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

(2) ERROR - This script is to disable the right button. 
the entire script can be seen here : http://jsfiddle.net/DQ6EX/

```
 captureEvents() is deprecated. This method doesn't do anything.
```

(3) ERROR - `event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.` Line 3345

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js

```
 // by a handler lower down the tree; reflect the correct value.


this.isDefaultPrevented = ( src.defaultPrevented || src.returnValue === false ||
            src.getPreventDefault && src.getPreventDefault() ) ? returnTrue : returnFalse;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer #(1)

You have to use the autoloader like it says in the demo page http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/demo/
You don't have to use all the stuff only which code you want to format.
For each of those formats you need a specific javascript file which starts like `shXXX.js`

```
function path()
{
    var args = arguments,
        result = []
        ;

    for(var i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
        result.push(args[i].replace('@', '/pub/sh/current/scripts/'));

    return result
};

SyntaxHighlighter.autoloader.apply(null, path(
    'applescript            @shBrushAppleScript.js',
    'actionscript3 as3      @shBrushAS3.js',
    'bash shell             @shBrushBash.js',
    'coldfusion cf          @shBrushColdFusion.js',
    'cpp c                  @shBrushCpp.js',
    'c# c-sharp csharp      @shBrushCSharp.js',
    'css                    @shBrushCss.js',
    'delphi pascal          @shBrushDelphi.js',
    'diff patch pas         @shBrushDiff.js',
    'erl erlang             @shBrushErlang.js',
    'groovy                 @shBrushGroovy.js',
    'java                   @shBrushJava.js',
    'jfx javafx             @shBrushJavaFX.js',
    'js jscript javascript  @shBrushJScript.js',
    'perl pl                @shBrushPerl.js',
    'php                    @shBrushPhp.js',
    'text plain             @shBrushPlain.js',
    'py python              @shBrushPython.js',
    'powershell ps posh     @shBrushPowerShell.js',
    'ruby rails ror rb      @shBrushRuby.js',
    'sass scss              @shBrushSass.js',
    'scala                  @shBrushScala.js',
    'sql                    @shBrushSql.js',
    'vb vbnet               @shBrushVb.js',
    'xml xhtml xslt html    @shBrushXml.js'
));
SyntaxHighlighter.all();
```

To answer #(2)

The deprecated warning about captureEvents() is just so it works for older Netscape Browsers I wouldn't worry about it, just a warning after all.

This actually works right, just when putting stuff in jsfiddle don't use `<script>` `</script>` tags it does those for you automatically.
Plus you should probably be using `<script type="text/javascript">...</script>`, it even tells you not to use them when you try to use  this error in yellow

> Input plain JavaScript code, no HTML.

```
var isNS = (navigator.appName == "Netscape") ? 1 : 0;

if(navigator.appName == "Netscape") document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN||Event.MOUSEUP);

function mischandler(){
return false;
}

function mousehandler(e){
var myevent = (isNS) ? e : event;
var eventbutton = (isNS) ? myevent.which : myevent.button;
if((eventbutton==2)||(eventbutton==3)) return false;
}
document.oncontextmenu = mischandler;
document.onmousedown = mousehandler;
document.onmouseup = mousehandler;
```

Comment: SSpoke ,thank you so much for taking time on this,appreciate it a lot, can I speak to you by chat? please I beg you I need to ask you just something that is so easy that no one wants to help me with, it's been 3 weeks I've been stuck on plus 2 weeks without being allowed to make questions.Please help me, its something so simple, I dont know what to do, I dont know javascript, I put the function altogether of an example I found but there is just one missing piece there are two buttons but one its not working.Please help me

Comment: Just paste the whole code in a jsfiddle and paste link here and I'll try to fix it.

Comment: spasibo , http://jsfiddle.net/2Y7sd/2/ , Minor Problem that would take just a minute of your time. Fade function with buttons used to fade the current content inside a column into the second content (hidden div).Content1 (id="c1") is there inside the column when the page loads,

press 2nd  "square" (div class="square") button---->
    (content1 fades) content2 (id="c2") appears.
Then press 1rst "square" button---->nothing happens
    no way of going back to content1 ( id="c1")         <-----------------ISSUE

Comment: forgot to put underframeworks and  Extensions jquery1.10.1 , onload is fine

Comment: < div id="details" >< div style="display" id="c1" > one of these two divs might not be in the right place that could be the reason for this minor issue,or there is something missing within the js function to make the first button go back to first content,honestly dont know, just guessing.

Comment: Okay I found the problem you have to use live from -> http://api.jquery.com/live/ which makes the square work after they were replaced with new squares from a different page using the $(this).html you could just never replace the squares and put them outside the html that gets replaced.. I'll reply with the fixed code soon.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, truly appreciate it so much, you are a great saint.

Comment: Okay I got really confused with your html.. it turns out when put into id="c1" the id="c2" you know that id="c1" will get lost forever since it gets overwritten by by id="c2". Okay a better fix would be to mess with the css using jquery to make c1 invisible and c2 visible etc.. I'll post the jsfiddle soon.

Comment: but can there be two contents in one column,I'm trying to say content 1 by pressing the button fades into content2 and then the option of going back to content1? thank you so much for helping me ,I'm a disaster in this, I'm sorry if I made a mess

Comment: I'm not good with jquery either, but I made it work. http://jsfiddle.net/2Y7sd/3/ It's messy and long but it does the job. Since the fades create a delay.. there is one problem if you press both boxes at the same time lol they both show up at one time. This can be fixed if you remove the fades. Don't forget I edited the HTML too I moved the id="c1" and id="c2" to entry-content's

Comment: you are a Genius and a great Saint, thank you so much, you are so kind, your work is amazing!! :) thank you so much again, I hope to this website will let me post questions again, I remember that I need to give you a bounty for  your previous work, I hope it will be soon. You are amazing and so kind, I really appreciate your work in this and all the answers you gave to my questions

Comment: Haha I managed to stumble upon you twice :P I felt I just needed to help out if I knew I could, I feel good too when someone helps me out when I'm stuck on something haha. BTW the bug I ment is try pressing the same red square like 10 times then press a gray square a few times and check what happens. It fixes itself up though, I'll try to raise your reputation so you can post questions again.

Comment: don't think the user will press it 10 times lol but this is amazing work and it's perfect,thank you so much, honestly you are so kind in taking your time in this, you are the only one who helped me in this while everyone else was just ignoring me or blocking me from asking about this issue.For all you do, you will receive a reward for it and I mean it in life,all the good things you do you will get it back 100 times more :)

Comment: I would like to give you 2 Bounties, but how many points do I need?

Comment: None don't worry about it :) just trying to make your points back to 100 so you can ask more questions in the future. I never got a bounty don't know how it works.. but I think if I get the bounty you will lose even more points and whats the point in that :P

Comment: I never cared about the points, I honestly prefer to give you two bounties because you really deserve them and sorry for saying but whoever didnt give you a bounty already is a fool.

Comment: I just need to know how many points will i need to give you the two bounties?

Comment: I think the only way I would get a bounty is if I answered a very hard question or atleast a question people didn't care to answer. I only answer the questions most people can already haha so yeah. Plus I'm bored that's why I go to this website.

Comment: Back to 104 points now you can post more questions :) good luck see-ya later.

Comment: Well the bounty definately should be more based on the dedication on the subject, finding a solution, the patience and goodwill and not forgetting the talent. This is what a bounty should be really about.

Comment: Thanks again, owe you 2 bounties you truly deserve them :), will start earning points from today to build them up. take care, dosvidanya

Comment: the voting was reversed but its ok, know what to do to get the points so hopefully soon I can give you the bounties you deserve them, can you please help me with this column is about the same one we spoke about a day ago.Trying to put this fade effect on two of four columns but if I do that even with one,all the columns stick together vertically instead of side to side, iam very lost please help me.

Comment: Is almost a month I´m stuck with this page that is supposed to be as the welcome page and these columns represent updates of each visual work i made from each month.Two months almost without finishing the site, this page is the obstacle in finishing it finally :(

Comment: would really appreciate it if you can help me if you have time, i edited an old question that had no results with this problem , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20013143/add-blending-javascript-function-to-make-content-fade-into-another-content-insid

Comment: Hi again, I'm sorry if I'm disturbing but if you can check a new minor issue I added it on a old question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19259932/how-add-various-divs-content-for-each-button-with-slide-toggle-function                      Still no new points achieved (did everything to try to fix this problem by fixing the questions,giving more details,etc but nothing) so I decided to start another account this week and try to gain points there. I need to build the points to give you two bounties that I have promised and intend to keep the promise until achieved.